# Confused about ** parameters in python function calls

Tags: python, syntax

For reference I am referring to the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/python-once-and-for-all-what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python)

The author of the answer gives the following code

```
def sum(*values, **options):
    s = 0
    for i in values:
        s = s + i
    if "neg" in options:
        if neg:
            s = -s
    return s

s = sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)            # returns 15
s = sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, neg=True)  # returns -15
s = sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, neg=False) # returns 15
```

However when I run on mine I get the following error

```
NameError: global name 'neg' is not defined
```

Can anyone explain this.  And in general, how does the function know when `values` ends and when `options` begins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if neg:
```

That line is buggy. It should be:

```
if options["neg"]:
```

---

> How does the function know when values ends and when options begins?

Unnamed values go in `*values`. Keyword arguments go in `**options`.

Comment: `if options.get("neg", False):` includes both `if` conditions.

Comment: @glglgl The shorter code seems to be slower by a factor of about 2.4. I'm guessing it's due to the `dict.get` method call.

Comment: @RussW Oups! Ok, but in the case of a multi-threading program, it is free of a race condition.

Comment: @glglgl I guess you got me there. +1

Answer (score 4):

You have made a small mistake. Change your code to the following and it should work. Just get the value of `"neg"` from the `options` dictionary, (`values` holds the unnamed arguments and `options` holds the keyword arguments)

```
>>> def sum(*values, **options):
        s = 0
        for i in values:
            s = s + i
        if "neg" in options:
            if options["neg"]:
                s = -s
        return s

>>> s = sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, neg=True)
>>> s
-15
>>> sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
15
>>> sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, neg=True)
-15
>>> sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, neg=False)
15
```

Although, as @glglgl pointed out, changing your code to the following consumes both the `if` statements into one.

```
>>> def sum(*values, **options):
    s = 0
    for i in values:
        s = s + i
    if options.get("neg", False):
            s = -s
    return s
```

**How does `get(...)` work?**

If the `options` dictionary doesn't have a key `"neg"`, (as handled by your first if condition), then, `get(...)` returns the default value of `False` and `s` is not negated, and if `options` contains `"neg"`, then it's value is returned, in which case, `s` is negated depending on the value in the dictionary.

Comment: `if options.get("neg", False):` includes both `if` conditions.

Comment: @glglgl : True. Thanks. Added to the answer and referenced to you. :)